# Why APOC (apoc-3.0.4.1-all.jar) not able to load in neo4j community edition, the same with other custom neo4j plugins?

Tags: neo4j

However, the plugin as loaded in the enterprise edition with issue even with warnings. Also, there is not way to check for logs.

error : Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@4006b29' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

Answer (score 0):

Both Community and enterprise version of Neo4j running on the same machine.
This is command used to find the running process

ps aux | grep java

Kill the enterprise process and restart the community edition.